# ZFS modules are not loaded in WSL 2 using Ubuntu 18.04: modprobe: FATAL: Module zfs not found in directory /lib/modules/4.19.84-microsoft-standard

Tags: ubuntu-18.04, windows-subsystem-for-linux, zfs

After installing zfs the following output is returned when running `zfs list`:

```
user@machine:~$ zfs list
The ZFS modules are not loaded.
Try running '/sbin/modprobe zfs' as root to load them.
user@machine:~$ sudo /sbin/modprobe zfs
modprobe: ERROR: ../libkmod/libkmod.c:586 kmod_search_moddep() could not open moddep file '/lib/modules/4.19.84-microsoft-standard/modules.dep.bin'
modprobe: FATAL: Module zfs not found in directory /lib/modules/4.19.84-microsoft-standard
```

How to user zfs with WSL2?

Comment: See https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/411977/openzfs-on-windows-subsystem-for-linux

Comment: @AndrewHenle That post is for WSL 1, this is regarding WSL 2

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Essentially, this error occurs because the ZFS Modules need to be built into the kernel, and the WSL2 kernel does not currently have ZFS Modules included.  Thankfully, there is a great tutorial on wsl.dev that covers manually building the kernel with ZFS.  I don't fully understand how it works, but just following the steps was easy enough: https://wsl.dev/wsl2-kernel-zfs/

Took me about 2 hours to walk through, but I did a bunch of research along the way ;)